# CSOM storing custom hidden field for document

Tags: sharepoint-online, csom, sharepoint-on-prem, .net

I want to store a custom, hidden field/property on a document. This property should be hidden from the user in the UI, and I don't want to create a content type for this.

Using

```
var document = client.Web.GetFileByServerRelativeUrl("/UBs%20Library/webhooks.png");
```

and then

```
document.ListItemAllFields["_hidden_documentId"] = "abc"
```

doesn't work as it requires a content type. I tried `document.ListItemAllFields.FieldValues` but that doesn't seem to be persisted?

Is it even possible to do this?

Answer (score 2):

You can use PropertyBag for that purposes. It can be used to store data at List Item level (and many others as well) and can be accessed from code only. Please find below how you can set and retrieve such a value:

```
        //Set value
        var item = <Code to obtain specific item/document>;
        item.Properties["_hidden_documentId"] = "DocumentId";
        item.Update();
        _clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

        //Get value
        var itemProperties = item.Properties;
        _clientContext.Load(itemProperties);
        _clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
        var documentId = itemProperties["_hidden_documentId"];
```

**Update**
Please find below piece of code which I tested and it works just fine:

```
        var file = _clientContext.Web.GetFileByUrl("Shared Documents/test.txt");
        file.Properties["_hidden_documentId"] = "DocumentId";
        file.Update();
        _clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

        //Get value
        var fileProperties = file.Properties;
        _clientContext.Load(fileProperties);
        _clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
        var documentId = fileProperties["_hidden_documentId"];
```

*Properties* property is available for *File* as well.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.
Using CSOM, how do I get the PropertyBag using `client.Web.GetFileByServerRelativeUrl()`? I.e. how to get to it from the `Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File` class?

Is this on the 2013 or 2016 csom?

Comment: It works exactly the same - File class have Properties as well, you just need to replace vat item =... with var file = client.Web.GetFileByServerRelativeUrl()

Comment: Intellisense is not giving me the PropertyBag for document, nor ListItem. I will check in the 2016 version.

Comment: I updated my answer. To clarify - I am using SharePoint Online.